# Identify context in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging

Currently our project is handling logging through static methods in a class. We use a transaction id to track the logs of a request and don't confuse with the logs of another.

But this has one concurrency problem.

1. request1 set up the transaction id (static)
2. request2  set up the transaction id (another one)
3. request1 logs, then it uses the id of request2.

Our architect propose to instantiate a logger and pass it as parameter in all functions, but that is quite annoying since there are a lot of functions calls, so that means adding a new parameter, not meaningful from a functional viewpoint, to hundreds of functions.

Any other solution I can think needs a way to, in any function, differentiate which context it belongs to, I mean, which request called the function.

I am very novice in nodejs, is there anykind of global variable or other mechanism that could me help here?

Comment: Why not use one of the popular logging libraries?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. Their logging system exists long before I entered the project. Their class use log4js to log, but wraps it, adding complexity and behavior around it. Anyway, I cannot remove this library, but if I could find a way to distinguish between requests I could make the new change easier.

Comment: How about storing the transaction id in the request object itself?

Comment: The request is not passed to most of the functions. We normally take the info from the request and call other functions to get the thing done. For example, imagine we take height and weight from the input and call to a function calculateBMI(height, weight). I need logging in that function, but I don't have the request. (it is just an example, the app is more complex and have a lot of nested fucntion calls)

Comment: You have to pass that transaction id or the logger itself through all functions, there is no way around. However as you probably pass some data through all the functions, you could just attaxh the id to that data. (And I'm curious if someone comes up with a better way, I'm facing the same problem at the moment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [blog](https://solidgeargroup.com/express-logging-global-unique-request-identificator-nodejs) sharing how this can be achieved.

I took a look on the library it used, it's referring to [cls-hooked](https://github.com/jeff-lewis/cls-hooked) which uses some internal/experimental Node.js features.

Hence, it's not quite recommended to use in production.

**Edited**

Recently, I discover a library when learning https://zipkin.io.  It uses https://github.com/othiym23/node-continuation-local-storage to keep track of value like thread-local storage.  Worth to take a look

Comment: You put me on the track for express-http-context, I think that would be enough for cooking the solution, but I'm not sure due to the concerns you expressed for production use.

Comment: @Mu_ As the internal/experimental feature in use, applying it to production need to be taken care every time you want to upgrade your Node.js.  If this is an helpful answer, I hope you can help mark it's helpful.  Thx.